# How to compare multiple string variables to sum data in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string-comparison

In my forecast I am forecasting multiple entities at once in Excel. For some entities I have to calculate some parts of the PL and BS in multiple iterations due to the structure of my data.

When I am done forecasting, I dump the results in FC_OUTPUT sheet and I want to group/sum the data together when the Entity (column D), GREN (column H) and IC-relation (column I) is the same. The code will loop through the rows and if it finds a match it has to add the rows together and delete the added row.
Below you may find my code. Michael Murphy (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8826022/michael-murphy)  made me a great piece of code to overcome most of my flaws that I made in my previous code.
Unfortunately, I still struggle with two key aspects:
 1. For sorting ICCol, I get an Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global'failed. Why sorting the other two columns work perfectly fine.
 2. Adding the row values from column 12 until column 96, is not working.
I am a bit out of my league with this and all help is very much appreciated.

```
Sub itest()

Dim EntityCol As Long, GRENCol As Long, ICCol As Long, ValueCol As Long, i As Long
Dim firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long, rngData As Range

Worksheets("FC_OUTPUT").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EntityCol = 4 ' column D
GRENCol = 8
ICCol = 9
ValueCol = 12 ' column L
firstrow = 7
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, EntityCol).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, EntityCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, ICCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, GRENCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range(Cells(firstrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 96))
     .Header = xlNo
     .Apply
End With


Set rngData = Range(Cells(firstrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 96)) ' this line should be adjusted but you'll need to also adjust firstrow and lastrow

With rngData
' Here I'll start a loop for every row going from the end to the beginning, to prevent issues when removing rows
    For i = lastrow To firstrow Step -1
    ' Here I'll use the If statement to check if the values are the same as the previous row

        If .Cells(i, EntityCol) = .Cells(i - 1, EntityCol) And _
                .Cells(i, GRENCol) = .Cells(i - 1, GRENCol) And _
                .Cells(i, ICCol) = .Cells(i - 1, ICCol) Then
            ' This is where you'll do your addition and delete
            .Cells(i - 1, ValueCol).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, ValueCol) + .Cells(i, ValueCol)
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A good start would be to clean up your variable declarations. `Dim entity_1, entity_2 As String` should be `Dim entity_1 as String, entity_2 As String` if you want two string variables. Right now `entity_1` is a variant variable the way you have it written.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fiddle with the range and double check column numbers to make sure that it fits your data, but this is an example of how I would go about your task. Maybe this will help steer you in a better direction. This assumes the data are sorted properly and this strictly compares each row to the row before:

```
Sub itest()

Dim EntityCol As Long, GRENCol As Long, ICCol As Long, ValueCol As Long, i As Long
Dim firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long, rngData As Range

EntityCol = 4 ' column D
GRENCol = 8
ICCol = 9
ValueCol = 12 ' column L
firstrow = 7
Set rngData = Cells ' this line should be adjusted but you'll need to also adjust firstrow and lastrow
' To find the last row, I'm assuming that your Entity column has values all the way to the end of your data
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, EntityCol).End(xlUp).Row

With rngData
' Here I'll start a loop for every row going from the end to the beginning, to prevent issues when removing rows
    For i = lastrow To firstrow Step -1
    ' Here I'll use the If statement to check if the values are the same as the previous row
        If .Cells(i, EntityCol) = .Cells(i - 1, EntityCol) And _
                .Cells(i, GRENCol) = .Cells(i - 1, GRENCol) And _
                .Cells(i, ICCol) = .Cells(i - 1, ICCol) Then
            ' This is where you'll do your addition and delete
            .Cells(i - 1, ValueCol).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, ValueCol) + .Cells(i, ValueCol)
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Here's my test data at the beginning:
[image: Before]

And after running:
[image: After]

Comment: Your code makes far more sense, than what I did. Sorting the data is a clever idea and going from the last row to the top to avoid issues with remove rows is definitely something that I could come up with.I struggle with issues to get it all up and running:

Comment: 1. sorting the data:
`With ActiveSheet.Sort

     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, EntityCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, ICCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(firstrow, GRENCol)), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range(Cells(firstrow, 1), Cells(lastrow, 96))
     .Header = xlNo
     .Apply

End With
`
Gives a run time error '1004' "Method 'Range'of object'_Global' failed for only sorting the ICCol. The other columns sort fine.

Comment: I edited the my original request, because these comment sections are very limited.

Comment: Your sort issue is a new issue and I believe it would be best to submit a new question for visibility. I'm going to leave this answer as-is.

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table? It might be a lot simpler than what you're attempting. You wouldn't have to worry about sorting or even VBA at all...

Comment: Pivot table might do the job mathematically, but I need to export the results in a template.
You already helped me a ton with your answer. Thanks a lot.